# Cross compilation of bison,yacc,flex for arm

Tags: linux

I have cross compiled LTP for arm .But before that I had installed dependencies like flex,bison,yacc.I want to know whether I have to cross compile the flex,bison and yacc as well to run ltp successfully on my arm board?? If yes then how to proceed with that.Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think, You do not need to cross compile `compile-time` dependencies but you have to cross compile `runtime` dependencies. And flex, bison seem like `compile-time` dependencies to me.

Answer (score 2):

Lex/Flex and Yacc/Bison just generate C/C++ code, so no need to cross-compile them.